# Copying with c# in geoserver

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, geoserver

Anybody knows about documentation or examples that how copy files (workspaces,shapes,..) in geoserver usinG C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This C# code will create a new workspace on GeoServer.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

...

string url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "geoserver");

byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<workspace><name>my_workspace</name></workspace>");
Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqstr.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

...
```

GeoServer has examples on how to do create workspaces, stores, layers and styles using cURL: [GeoServer cURL REST Configuration Examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html).
Then you can convert the cURL examples using the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs for [geoerver's REST API](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/restconfig/rest-config-api.html). Scroll down a bit to the Workspaces section and you'll notice that you need to send a GET/POST/PUT method to the server for the workspace you want to create/copy.

Comment: Thanks but for me the page of Geoserver is not very helpfull.